# Difference between parallel HDF5 MPI I/O transfer modes (Independent vs Collective)

Tags: parallel-processing, hdf5, mpi-io

According to the HDF5 manual, the "MPI I/O transfer mode" can be set through the HDF5 function `H5Pset_dxpl_mpio(...)`. One of the parameters is the transfer mode. It can be either H5FD_MPIO_INDEPENDENT (default) or H5FD_MPIO_COLLECTIVE. I can't find the difference between the two options. What is it? Is H5FD_MPIO_COLLECTIVE necessary if I am computing the offset manually (per mpi process) when writing in a hyperslab?

In a small parallel program that write one shared file between all processes, I tried to switch between the two options, there is no difference, no warning or crash.

Answer (score 2):

Independent vs Collective is a MPI I/O concept (not specific to the HDF5 API). There is an old HDF Group document that discusses this. Ref: [Performance Comparison of Collective I/O And Independent I/O with Derived Datatypes (ca. 2006)](https://docs.hdfgroup.org/hdf5/rfc/coll_ind_dd6.pdf)

In short, "***Independent IO** means that each process does IO independently, while **Collective IO** requires all processes to participate when doing IO operations. The advantage of Collective IO is that it allows MPI-IO to do optimization to improve IO performance.*"

The Introduction has a good example that explains the difference in the 2 processes.

You may not see an performance difference because you are writing small amounts of data.

Google "mpi independent vs collective" to find more MPI IO references (not HDF5 specific).